# Why do I need to include https in externals for my rollup.config.js

Tags: typescript, https, yarnpkg, commonjs, rollupjs

```
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json'
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins'

export default {
  input: "./index.ts",
  output: {
    file: "./dist/main.compiled.js",
    format: "cjs",
    sourcemap: true
  },
  external: ['https'], //Why???
  plugins: [    
    typescript(), 
    commonjs(),
    json(), 
    builtins(),
    resolve()    
  ]
}
```

If I don't include 'https' in my externals I get this error:

```
xhr = new global.XMLHttpRequest();
          ^
TypeError: global.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor
```

when I import this package and use services which creates httpAgent for my axios client

```
import { Agent } from 'https'
httpAgent: new Agent({ keepAlive: true })
```

I thought builtins() solves this.
I am using `yarn run rollup -c` to build my project

Comment: As mentioned from [rollup-plugin-node-builtins](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/rollup-plugin-node-builtins), some modules require [rollup-plugin-node-globals](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/rollup-plugin-node-globals)

Comment: import globals from 'rollup-plugin-node-globals'
  plugins: [    
    typescript(), 
    commonjs(),
    json(), 
    builtins(),
    globals(),
    resolve({
      browser: false,
      preferBuiltins: true
    })    
  ]

Tried this, but same error